# Which Class used for writing characters rather than bytes?

Tags: java

Which class should be used in situations that require writing characters rather than bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PrintWriter will be useful

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

Comment: PrintWriter is usually a *bad* idea as it swallows exceptions. Writer is the main abstraction to focus on.

Answer (score 13):

Please take a look at `java.io.Writer` and subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to know about I/O in Java is that **streams** (`InputStream` and `OutputStream` etc.) are used for reading and writing binary data (you read or write bytes exactly as they are in the file), and **readers** and **writers** (`Reader` and `Writer` etc.) are for reading and writing characters.

Readers and writers are a layer on top of streams. A `Reader` interprets the bytes from an `InputStream` using a character encoding (such as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII) to convert them into characters, and a `Writer` uses a character encoding to turn characters into bytes.

Comment: Not exactly. Readers and Writers are *not* directly related to streams. Only `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter` connect streams with reader/writers with the help of encodings.